# Why google map with kml always zoom to the max level?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I made a google map app use google map api v3 and kml file. However, sometime it work, and sometime it always zoom to the max level and center is not mine options.center(near Africa).

Why is it?

And my kml file was uploaded to mine Google Map account.

```
function initialize1() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.566991,114.315491);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 10,
center: myLatlng,
overviewMapControl:true,
overviewMapControlOptions: {
 opened:true  
},
scaleControl:true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map1= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas1"), myOptions);


var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://maps.google.com/maps/ms? **************',
{suppressInfoWindows: true});
nyLayer.setMap(map1);
google.maps.event.addListener(nyLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
showInDiv(text);
});
}
```

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 0):

That behavior occurs when the kml file doesn't exist/can't be found.  You haven't provided the URL of the file to allow testing that.

Another thing to check would be the validity of the file:
http://www.feedvalidator.org/

You could also check the [KmlLayerStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerStatus) provided by the API to see what it reports.

Comment: I test this kml file in http://www.feedvalidator.org/ and find that just the namespace of kml is not validate. It suggest using http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2, but I used http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 .However, how to explain that it show well sometime. Just I open my webpage again, it work..... >.<

Comment: I guess you will need to capture the "KmlStatus" when it fails to load.